# Batch that writes another batch without using " echo [code] >>[new place].bat " repetitively

Tags: mod-rewrite, batch-file, windows-xp, echo

Ok my question today is obviously very difficult, by the title my task doesn't seem difficult but trust me this is not your usual one.

What im looking to do is run a batch file to compile another with a variable set inside of the batch file being run. Heres the catch though. I don't want to have to write the batch file from within the coding. heres what I mean.

Here is an example of the finished batch file.

```
@echo off
color a
title my compiled batch
echo.
echo.
echo  This is the batch file that was compiled from the one I was using to create it.
echo.
echo.
pause
exit
```

Here is the compiler as you are thinking of it most likely.

```
[new.bat]
@echo off
color a
cls
echo.
echo type your name.
echo.
echo.
set input=
set /p input=Name:  ( I typed "my compiled batch" in this input area)
echo @echo off >>new.bat
echo color a >>new.bat
echo title %input% >>new.bat
echo echo. >>new.bat
echo echo. >>new.bat
echo This is the batch file that was compiled from the one I was using to create it. >>new.bat
echo echo. >>new.bat
echo echo. >>new.bat
echo pause >>new.bat
echo exit >>new.bat
```

Here is what I want to be able to do with mine seeing as how its 784 lines long.

```
echo "@echo off
color a
title my compiled batch
echo.
echo.
echo This is the batch file that was compiled from the one I was using to create it.
echo.
echo.
pause
exit" >> new.bat
```

So basically I want to compile the batch file as a single string but it still go into the "new.bat" as if I had coded it all myself.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: If you have large blocks of static text, you can store that in a template file and copy it (appended) to the new batch... just using `echo >>` for the %variable% parts. Another approach would be to store the entire template in a text file, and copy it line by line using a FOR loop (see `FOR /?` for guidance) and have some hardcoded tokens that you would search for and replace with the input variables. Someone will no doubt be along shortly to tell you how, I'm off to bed.. good night :)

Comment: Could you please code that out? your answer seems as though it would work but I don't know exactly how I would arrange that. @Mr Fuzzy Button

Comment: Could you please code that out? your answer seems as though it would work but I don't know exactly how I would arrange that. @Mr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's solve this problem via two or three interesting tricks:

- The code to be compiled is enclosed between a certain label/line that identify it; for example `:EMBEDDED_CODE`.
- Use `findstr /N "^:EMBEDDED_CODE" "%~F0"` command to get the begin and end lines of the embedded code. Note that the search string start with `^` to avoid find the line of the `findstr` command itself.
- Use `for /F "skip=%begin% ...` command and compare the line number vs. %end% to extract the embedded code.
- Enclose the variable(s) you want to replace between exclamation marks instead percents, and Enable Delayed Expansion at beginning.

Here it is:

**EDIT:** I changed `findstr` by `find` in order to preserve the colon in :LABELS in the embedded code.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color a
cls
echo.
echo type your name.
echo.
echo.
set input=
set /p input=Name:  ( I typed "my compiled batch" in this input area)

REM Get begin and end lines of the embedded code
set begin=
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^:EMBEDDED_CODE" "%~F0"') do (
   if not defined begin (
      set begin=%%a
   ) else (
      set end=%%a
   )
)

REM Extract the embedded lines into new.bat file,
REM the replacement of variables enclosed in exclamation marks is automatic:
(for /F "skip=%begin% tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /N /V "" "%~F0"') do (
   if %%a equ %end% goto :EOF
   echo(%%b
)) > new.bat
goto :EOF


:EMBEDDED_CODE Begin
@echo off
color a
title !input!
echo.
echo.
echo This is the batch file that was compiled from the one I was using to create it. 
echo Created on !date! @ !time!
echo.
echo.
pause
exit
:EMBEDDED_CODE End
```

Antonio

Comment: Dear god, why did he choose the most complex way?

Comment: ok this works except for one part. when I entered code in between :EMBEDED_CODE Begin and :EMBEDDED_CODE End, a few errors occurred not from the batch process @aacini

Comment: 1st. It successfully copies over everything with the exception of my labels. For instance when I copy the label ":Menu" it puts into the new.bat "Menu". 2nd I have a variable set the exact same way that you do in your answer except for instead of using that variable to replace the title im using it to replace where my directory is changed to on the "cd" command. For instance on the batch ABOVE it is set to "set input= set /p input=Name:" and then it copies the following line with the input of that variable. "!input!"  @aacini

Comment: but my problem is not there it is when I use if for the following. set input= set /p input=User Account: [now for the line being miss copied] it says to copy this "cd C:\documents and settings\!input!\desktop" but when it copies, it only copies that line exactly how it is and not replaced with the input from my variable "!input!" @aacini

Comment: @cmd: 1st. I fixed the program to preserve semicolon in labels. 2nd Excuse me, but I don't understand your problem. Please, **edit** your question above and add a small segment that show the problem. Write something like "with this _embedded code_ I get this _result_, but I want this _one_ instead".

Answer (score 1):

Given BATCHTEMPLATE.BAT (which is a `text` file - but [EDITPLUS](http://www.editplus.com) can syntax-highlight `.bat` files...

```
@echo off
color a
$name
echo.
echo.
echo  This is the batch file that was compiled from the one I was using to create it.
$date
echo.
echo.
pause
exit
```

Then running this batch:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
::
SET name=
SET /p name="Name: "
::
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (batchtemplate.bat) DO (
 ECHO %%i|FINDSTR /b /c:"$" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO.%%i) ELSE (
 IF /i %%i==$name ECHO.title  %name%
 IF /i %%i==$date ECHO.ECHO Created %date%
 )
)
)>new.bat

TYPE new.bat
```

using

```
echo MY BATCH|thisbatch
```

yields

```
Name: @echo off
color a
title  MY BATCH
echo.
echo.
echo  This is the batch file that was compiled from the one I was using to create it.
ECHO Created 24/03/2013
echo.
echo.
pause
exit
```

I use a similar system to write programs...

Comment: ok this works except for one part. when I entered code in between :EMBEDED_CODE Begin and :EMBEDDED_CODE End, a few errors occurred not from the batch process. @PeterWright

Comment: 1st. It successfully copies over everything with the exception of my labels.
 For instance when I copy the label ":Menu" it puts into the new.bat "Menu".
 2nd I have a variable set the exact same way that you do in your answer except for instead of using that variable
 to replace the title im using it to replace where my directory is changed to on the "cd" command.
 For instance on the batch ABOVE it is set to "set input= set /p input=Name:" 
and then it copies the following line with the input of that variable. "!input!" @peterWright

Comment: but my problem is not there it is when I use if for the following.  set input= 
 set /p input=User Account:  [now for the line being miss copied] it says to copy
 this "cd C:\documents and settings\!input!\desktop" but when it copies, it only 
copies that line exactly how it is and not replaced with the input from my variable
 "!input!"@PeterWright

Comment: @cmd: Do you realise that your comments refer to Aacini's solution, not mine? To comment on Aacini's solution, you need to use `add comment` on the horizontal line below **THAT** solution.